# How to find a random bit 1 (or 0) in a dynamic_bit set?

Tags: boost

How to find a random bit 1 (or 0) in a `dynamic_bit` set?

**Example**:

```
bitset: 101101
index : 012345

find_random_bit_1() return 3
find_random_bit_0() return 4
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do would be to keep selecting bits until you find the one you're after:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc, typename Rnd = boost::mt19937>
size_t select_random_bit(boost::dynamic_bitset<T, Alloc> const& bs, Rnd& random, bool target = true) {
    boost::uniform_int<size_t> pick(0,bs.size()-1);

    if (bs.empty() || (bs.all() && !target) || (bs.none() && target))
        throw std::range_error("select_random_bit");

    while(true) {
        auto index = pick(random);
        if (bs[index] == target)
            return index;
    }

    throw std::logic_error("select_random_bit");
}
```

The most important thing is the precondition checks to avoid infinite loops. Of course, the performance could be bad for non-uniform data, but it's the simplest way to arrive at a fair distribution

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/759c3c9284869971)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T, typename Alloc, typename Rnd = boost::mt19937>
size_t select_random_bit(boost::dynamic_bitset<T, Alloc> const& bs, Rnd& random, bool target = true) {
    boost::uniform_int<size_t> pick(0,bs.size()-1);

    if (bs.empty() || (bs.all() && !target) || (bs.none() && target))
        throw std::range_error("select_random_bit");

    while(true) {
        auto index = pick(random);
        if (bs[index] == target)
            return index;
    }

    throw std::logic_error("select_random_bit");
}

boost::dynamic_bitset<> generate_testdata(boost::mt19937& rng) {
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> bs(1024+rng()%1024); // [1024,2048) bits

    boost::uniform_smallint<uint8_t> gen(0, 1);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < bs.size(); ++i)
        bs[i] = gen(rng);

    return bs;
}

int main() {
    using namespace boost;

    mt19937 rng(42); // seed it
    auto data = generate_testdata(rng);

    std::cout << data.count() << " out of " << data.size() << " bits are set\n";

    std::cout << "\nTrue: ";
    for (int i = 0; i <10; ++i)
        std::cout << select_random_bit(data, rng/*, true*/) << " ";

    std::cout << "\nFalse: ";
    for (int i = 0; i <10; ++i)
        std::cout << select_random_bit(data, rng, false) << " ";
}
```

Prints 10 true and 10 false bits, e.g.:

```
562 out of 1126 bits are set

True: 1104 394 684 716 624 492 102 817 392 616 
False: 335 589 971 785 1069 948 865 290 51 652
```

Comment: Thanks. I had found my own way. I generate a random index. 
```c++
 // find a random bit
 std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, a_bit_set.count() - 1);
 auto random_bit_index = 0;
 random_bit_index = dist(mt);
 if (!a_bit_set.test(random_bit_index))
 {
  random_bit_index = a_bit_set.find_next(random_bit_index);
 }
 if (random_bit_index == dynamic_bitset<>::npos)
 {
  random_bit_index = a_bit_set.find_first();
 }
```

Comment: But I will try your way. I think it's better (y)